# Associated Parameter Restriction using Functional Dependency

Tags: haskell, types, functional-dependencies

The function f below, for a given type 'a', takes a parameter of type 'c'. For different types 'a', 'c' is restricted in different ways. Concretely, when 'a' is any Integral type, 'c' should be allowed to be any 'Real' type. When 'a' is Float, 'c' can ONLY be Float.

One attempt is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
MultiParamTypeClasses,
FlexibleInstances,
FunctionalDependencies,
UndecidableInstances #-}

class AllowedParamType a c | a -> c

class Foo a where
    f :: (AllowedParamType a c) => c -> a

fIntegral :: (Integral a, Real c) => c -> a
fIntegral = error "implementation elided"

instance (Integral i, AllowedParamType i d, Real d) => Foo i where
    f = fIntegral
```

For some reason, GHC 7.4.1 complains that it "could not deduce (Real c) arising from a use of fIntegral". It seems to me that the functional dependency should allow this deduction. In the instance, a is unified with i, so by the functional dependency, d should be unified with c, which in the instance is declared to be 'Real'. What am I missing here?

Functional dependencies aside, will this approach be expressive enough to enforce the restrictions above, or is there a better way? We are only working with a few different values for 'a', so there will be instances like:

```
instance (Integral i, Real c) => AllowedParamType i c
instance AllowedParamType Float Float
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say `class AllowedParamType a c | a -> c`, you say that given any type `a` as the first parameter, there is at most one type `c` that can be used as the second parameter. But then you say when the first type is an `Integral` type, *any* `Real` type can be used as the second parameter. Ideally GHC would give you an error message pointing this out.

Comment: This is not the true. It just means that a uniquely determines b so above kind of instances are allowed.

Comment: Satvik is right, the uniqueness of the fundep *shouldn't* be what's making the code not compile. However, dave4420 is also has the right idea: the fundep isn't going to work in the long run because I don't want to restrict the parameter type of Int to one type of Real for the whole program.

Comment: @dave4420: That's not what the instance says, though. It's *actually* saying "when the first type is *any type at all*, the second type is also any type, and oh by the way make sure they have `Integral` and `Real` instances, respectively". The `Integral` constraint is ignored when selecting an instance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do - do you just want to be able to declare different implementations of `f` for several different source and target types? Is the target always `Real a => a` or does it sometimes _have_ to be `Float`? (i.e. can you do `class F a where f :: Real r => c -> a`?) Your comment suggests that you don't mean that a depends on c but your code appears to be trying to make c depend on a. Can you give a bit more context? Would it be sufficient to write a function `f :: Real a => a -> a` and just precompose with some fromIntegral type function when needed?

Comment: 'r' is not always a Real type, it can also include some specific Data values that we have declared (all of which will be Num), though the specific implementation of f depends on the concrete Num type. To be clear about the relationship between 'a' and 'c', I would like to make a few instances of Foo for (Num a). For each instance, there is either one (unique) possible type for c (like Float), or an entire typeclass (like Real). 'c' need not be related to 'a', they can be "independent" types in some cases (for our user-defined types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this one's been nagging at me. given the wide variety of instances, 
let's go the whole hog and get rid of any relationship between the 
source and target type other than the presence of an instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances,TypeSynonymInstances,MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Foo a b where f :: a -> b
```

Now we can match up pairs of types with an `f` between them however we like, for example:

```
instance Foo Int Int where f = (+1)
instance Foo Int Integer where f = toInteger.((7::Int) -)
instance Foo Integer Int where f = fromInteger.(^ (2::Integer))
instance Foo Integer Integer where f = (*100)
instance Foo Char Char where f = id
instance Foo Char String where f = (:[])  -- requires TypeSynonymInstances
instance (Foo a b,Functor f) => Foo (f a) (f b) where f = fmap f -- requires FlexibleInstances
instance Foo Float Int where f = round
instance Foo Integer Char where f n = head $ show n
```

This does mean a lot of explicit type annotation to avoid `No instance for...` and `Ambiguous type` error messages.
For example, you can't do `main = print (f 6)`, but you can do `main = print (f (6::Int)::Int)`

You could list *all* of the instances with the standard types that you want, 
which could lead to an awful lot of repetition, our you could light the blue touchpaper and do:

```
instance Integral i => Foo Double i where f = round -- requires FlexibleInstances
instance Real r => Foo Integer r where f = fromInteger -- requires FlexibleInstances
```

Beware: this does **not** mean "Hey, if you've got an integral type `i`, 
you can have an instance `Foo Double i` for free using this handy round function",
it means: "**every** time you have *any* type `i`, it's definitely an instance 
`Foo Double i`. By the way, I'm using `round` for this, so unless your type `i` is `Integral`, 
we're going to fall out." That's a big issue for the `Foo Integer Char` instance, for example.

This can easily break your other instances, so if you now type `f (5::Integer) :: Integer` you get

```
Overlapping instances for Foo Integer Integer
  arising from a use of `f'
Matching instances:
  instance Foo Integer Integer
  instance Real r => Foo Integer r
```

You can change your pragmas to include OverlappingInstances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, FlexibleInstances,TypeSynonymInstances,MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

So now `f (5::Integer) :: Integer` returns 500, so clearly it's using the more specific `Foo Integer Integer` instance.

I think this sort of approach might work for you, defining many instances by hand, carefully considering when to go completely wild 
making instances out of standard type classes. (Alternatively, there aren't all that many standard types, and as we all know, `notMany choose 2 = notIntractablyMany`, so you could just list them all.)

Answer (score 3):

A possibly better way, is to use constraint kinds and type families (GHC extensions, requires GHC 7.4, I think). This allows you to specify the constraint as part of the class instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Foo a where
   type ParamConstraint a b :: Constraint
   f :: ParamConstraint a b => b -> a

instance Integral i => Foo i where
   type ParamConstraint i b = Real b
   f = fIntegral
```

<sub>EDIT: Upon further experimentation, there are some subtleties that mean that this doesn't work as expected, specifically, `type ParamConstraint i b = Real b` is too general. I don't know a solution (or if one exists) right now.</sub>

Comment: I was wondering if constraint kinds might do the trick. What are these subtleties?

Comment: Well, this solution will work nicely as long as you don't add any other instances...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion to solve a more general problem, not yours specifically (I need more detail yet first - I promise to check later). I'm writing it in case other people are searching for a solution to a similar problem to you, I certainly was in the past, before I discovered SO. SO is especially great when it helps you try a radically new approach.

I used to have the work habit:

1. Introduce a multi-parameter type class (Types hanging out all over the place, so...)
2. Introduce functional dependencies (Should tidy it up but then I end up needing...)
3. Add FlexibleInstances (Alarm bells start ringing. There's a reason the compiler has this off by default...)
4. Add UndecidableInstances (GHC is telling you you're on your own, because it's not convinced it's up to the challenge you're setting it.)
5. Everything blows up. Refactor somehow.

Then I discovered the joys of [type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simonpj/Talk%3aFunWithTypeFuns) (functional programming for types (hooray) - multi-parameter type classes are (a bit like) logic programming for types). My workflow changed to:

1. Introduce a type class including an associated type, i.e. replace

   ```
   class MyProblematicClass a b | a -> b where
     thing :: a -> b
     thang :: b -> a -> b
   ```

   with

   ```
   class MyJustWorksClass a where
     type Thing a :: * -- Thing a is a type (*), not a type constructor (* -> *)
     thing :: a -> Thing a
     thang :: Thing a -> a -> Thing a
   ```
2. Nervously add FlexibleInstances. Nothing goes wrong at all.
3. Sometimes fix things by using constraints like `(MyJustWorksClass j,j~a)=>` instead of `(MyJustWorksClass a)=>` or `(Show t,t ~ Thing a,...)=>` instead of `(Show (Thing a),...) =>` to help ghc out. (`~` essentially means 'is the same type as')
4. Nervously add FlexibleContexts. Nothing goes wrong at all.
5. Everything works.

The reason "Nothing goes wrong at all" is that ghc *calculates* the type `Thing a` using my type function `Thang` rather than trying to *deduce* it using a merely a bunch of assertions that there's a function there and it ought to be able to work it out.

Give it a go! Read [Fun with Type Functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simonpj/Talk%3aFunWithTypeFuns) *before* reading the [manual](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families)!

Comment: The reason I tried a new typeclass for my solution is because I knew an associated type wouldn't allow me to express that the constraint is a class rather than a concrete type (since associated types have to be concrete). Instead I used a fundep, but this suffers the same problem as the associated type synonym.

Comment: @Eric: The problem being that there's not a functional dependency? Your answer in the comments suggests not. The relationship between source type and target type you describe there appears to be many-to-many.