# Haskell: Why does GHC not infer type in this typeclass with fundeps?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I'm trying to use typeclasses and functional dependencies to get a *type function* that can transform say, `Int`  to `Cont Int` in the code below, then use it in another typeclass as shown below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

newtype TestData a b = TestData b
newtype Cont a = Cont a

class TypeConv (repr :: * -> *) a b | repr a -> b where
class Lift repr a where
    liftOp :: (TypeConv repr a a') => a -> repr a'

instance TypeConv (TestData a) Int (Cont Int) where

instance Lift (TestData a) Int where
    liftOp i = TestData (Cont i)
```

And here's the error from ghci 7.4.2

```
src/Test.hs:13:26:
    Could not deduce (a' ~ Cont Int)
    from the context (Full (TestData a) Int a')
      bound by the type signature for
                 liftOp :: Full (TestData a) Int a' => Int -> TestData a a'
      at src/Test.hs:13:5-32
      a' is a rigid type variable bound by
         the type signature for
           liftOp :: Full (TestData a) Int a' => Int -> TestData a a'
         at src/Test.hs:13:5
    In the return type of a call of `Cont'
    In the first argument of `TestData', namely `(Cont i)'
    In the expression: TestData (Cont i)
```

Given that the `TypeConv` typeclass has a fundep that I read as: "Given `repr` and `a`, we can infer `b`" and provided an instance for `Int`, why can't ghc infer that `a' ~ Cont Int` ?

Comment: Is the first parameter of `TestData` just there to try to make the types work? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with it. Do you actually want this instance to create `liftOp :: Int -> Cont Int` but you had to wrap it in `TestData`?

Comment: That sort of type refinement simply isn't done with FunDeps. I don't know the details, but something would be hard to implement correctly in that. Use type families to do that stuff.

Comment: @AndrewC: I just reduced my problem to a small test, so the superfluous type parm `repr` has no use here. The idea is that `repr` and `a` should both decide `a'` in `TypeConv`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a type function, use Type Families - that's what they're for. Type Families are easy and do what you expect.

Often the reason that the compiler didn't infer your type is that you specified a functional dependency (logical relationship) rather than a function (calculating tool). Using fundeps is notoriously counter-intuitive, partly because you're doing logic programming at the type level whilst doing functional programming at the value level. Switch! Use functions at the type level, with the lovely Type Families extension. Comes with free lambda fridge magnet with just four tokens (p&p not included).

---

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve, but here's an example - correct me if I'm heading in the wrong direction. You'll need

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

Then we can define a class that includes a local type synonym, `TypeConv` which is our type function:

```
class Lift a where
    type TypeConv a
    liftOp :: a -> TypeConv a
```

And then we could make an instance

```
instance Lift Int where
    type TypeConv Int = TestData (Cont Int)
    liftOp i = TestData (Cont i)
```

and if we just want to wrap in `Cont`, we could do

```
instance Lift Integer where
    type TypeConv Integer = Cont Integer
    liftOp i = Cont i
```

and you can go crazy with

```
instance Lift Char where
    type TypeConv Char = [String]
    liftOp c = replicate 4 (replicate 5 c)
```

which lets you have

```
*Main> liftOp (5::Int)
TestData (Cont 5)

*Main> liftOp (5::Integer)
Cont 5

*Main> liftOp '5'
["55555","55555","55555","55555"]
```

Comment: That worked! I also noticed that some places where I had to put the type manually, it was now being inferred correctly.
Any pointer to where I can learn the differences between Type Families and Functional Dependencies that you mention here would be great!

Comment: Excellent! I put two links at the bottom of [another answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399796/associated-parameter-restriction-using-functional-dependency/12409935#12409935) Those are my favourite introductions, but neither's ideal. The 1st explains a bit of the motivation and uses the idea _much_ more generally than I have here. They do make some comparisons. Here I've used Type Families (which could be called Explicit Type Functions) to define a type function across class instances by pattern matching at the type level.

Comment: I think the difference between a functional dependency and an explicit type function is the same as the difference between the functional dependency of data in a table on the primary key (which restricts what you can put in the primary key) and a function definition (which determines what the answer is). The typechecker applies a function every time but with a fundep you might be expecting it to search the list of instances (records in a table) to find a type, when it was hoping you'd give it the row it needed, and concludes "this type could be anything", when you know it could deduce which.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew is unnecessarily critical of `fundeps` sure, type functions are easier, but functional dependencies often provide extra flexibility.  In this case, you simply have to accept longer class definitions

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, 
             FunctionalDependencies, 
             FlexibleInstances, 
             FlexibleContexts #-}

newtype TestData a b = TestData b
newtype Cont a = Cont a

class TypeConv (repr :: * -> *) a b | repr a -> b
class TypeConv repr a b => Lift repr a b | repr a -> b where
    liftOp :: a -> repr b

instance TypeConv (TestData a) Int (Cont Int)

instance Lift (TestData a) Int (Cont Int) where
    liftOp i = TestData (Cont i)
```

Of course, the type function based approach does look nicer, and is probably preferable.